# Displaying subscripted symbols with TraditionalForm

Tags: output-formatting, symbols

I have pasted this code in from *Mathematica* 10

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
a = Subscript[q, m]
b = Subscript[q, f]
TraditionalForm[a + b]
```

Though the definition of `a` and `b` look of identical form when pasted here, I entered `a`  explicitly using `Subscript` while `b` is entered q then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. The Head of `a` is `Subscript` and the Head of `b` is `Symbol` (which is what I want in order to work with traditional notation in my field).  In `TraditionalForm`, `a` is formatted correctly while `b` is formatted as `q\[Underbracket]Subscript\[Underbracket]f`.

So can I use something of the form `q sub f` as a symbol and still get nice output in traditional form?

I this case I think it is useful to post an image capture of the notebook:

[image]

Comment: Quoting http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html "`Subscript[x,y]` formats as ... in StandardForm and TraditionalForm" - but that might not be what you want?

Comment: Everything seems to be working OK here.  We need a complete example where the output is not as you desire.

Comment: I've added a screen capture which I think demonstrates the OPs problem.  I *think* the question is related to creating subscripted symbols and whether or not the Notation package is the right way to do this.